# Acessar arrays multidimensionais de um input no php

Tags: php, input

Tenho vários arrays de imagens no seguinte formato:

```
<input type="file" name="imagens[$id][]">
```

O `$id` é mudado dinamicamente. Como faço para acessar pegar algum dos dados da imagem, o name por exemplo, no php?

Atualizando:

```
Array
(
    [45] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1.jpg
            [1] => 2.jpg
            [2] => 
        )

    [44] => Array
        (
            [0] => 4.jpg
            [1] => 5.jpg
            [2] => 
        )

)
```

Solução:
Consegui acessar dessa forma:

```
$_FILES['imagens']['name'][$id]
```

Comment: `$_FILES['imagens'][0]['tmp_name']`, na dúvida da um `print_r($_FILES);`

Comment: Usa um `echo <pre>;` com `print_r($array);` em vez de `var_dump`, esta ruim de ler.

Comment: Olá @GuilhermeLautert , atualizei dessa forma

Answer (score 0):

Como você não sabe o valor da chave, o ideal é percorrer o array:

```
foreach($_FILES['imagens'] as $img){
   echo $img['tmp_name'];
}
```

Comment: Olá, eu tentei dessa forma, mas ele não reconhece os índice 'tmp_name'. Testei com var_dump, e não reconhece nunehum dos índices tradicionais   do file(name, size, etc). Os índices são todos como número, vou colar o que encontrou.

Answer (score 0):

Primeiramente note que em seu `array` não a chave `name` ou `tmp_name` que é comum quando se usa `$_FILES` no PHP.

Desta forma pressuponho que você deve estar usando o método errado para capturar o dado do formulário. (deve estar usando `$_POST`).

Geralmente quando se quer fazer um *upload* de arquivo(s), se usa :

```
<form action="upload.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    <input type="file" name="imagens[$id][]">
</form>
```

Note que no *form* esta `method="post"`, contudo no PHP você deve capturá-lo pelo `$_FILES`. O que deve lhe gerar um array assim :

```
Array
(
    [45] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array 
                (
                    [name] => 1.jpg
                    [type] => image/jpeg
                    [tmp_name] => /tmp/php/php6hst32
                    [size] => 98174
                )
            [1] => Array 
                (
                    [name] => 2.jpg
                    [type] => image/jpeg
                    [tmp_name] => /tmp/php/php6hst32
                    [size] => 98174
                )
        )

    [44] => Array
        (
            [0] =>  Array 
                (
                    [name] => 4.jpg
                    [type] => image/jpeg
                    [tmp_name] => /tmp/php/php6hst32
                    [size] => 98174
                )
        )
)
```

Para manipular seu conteúdo pode se usar `foreach`:

```
foreach($_FILES as $id => $files){
    foreach($files as $k => $file){
        $name = $file['name'];
        $tmpName = $file['tmp_name'];

        printf("name : %s\n tmpName : %s", $name, $tmpName);
    }
}
```